# help me to prove this

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functional-inequalities

I would like to prove that $n/k!$ for $k$ that holds $k\leq \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$ will always be bigger/equal to $1/2$. I tried to use stirling but got stuck.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jonatan

Comment: Please _use_ $\LaTeX$ for better display of mathematical expressions and also _mention_ the base of the logarithm _explicitly_.

Comment: The problem would be easier to parse if you state the hypothesis first, $k \le \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$, and then the desired conclusion, $\frac{n}{k!} \ge \frac{1}{2}$.